# NHunspell Hyphenation crashing without any error or exception

Tags: c#, .net, hunspell, nhunspell

I am trying to use NHunspell NuGet package to hyphenate words in an ASP.NET MVC application.

Here is the code that crashes the application:

```
using NHunspell;

namespace MyApp.Hyphenation.NHunspell;

public class ConcreteHyphenator : IHyphenator
{
    public string Hyphenate(string text, string language = "")
    {
        using var hyphenator = string.IsNullOrEmpty(language) ? new Hyphen("..\\MyApp.Hyphenation.NHunspell\\Assets\\en.dic") : new Hyphen(language);

        return hyphenator.Hyphenate(text).HyphenatedWord; // APP CRASHES HERE
    }
}
```

I am using the 1.2.5544.16953 version of the NHunspell package and .NET 7.

I *did* need to copy the `Hunspellx64.dll` manually from the `C:\Users\my-name\.nuget\packages\nhunspell\1.2.5554.16953\content` to the MyApp's bin directory. I couldn't instantiate the `Hyphen` class at all before that.

When checking the Windows error log, I got this error code: `0xc0000374`.

I also confirmed that the `.dic` file is properly loading by calling `File.ReadAllBytes` on the same path, and it worked fine. Suppling the resulting byte array to the `Hyphen` constructor worked as well.

But the call to the `Hyphenate` method crashes every time.

Any ideas on where to go from here?

Comment: Does it work in development?

Comment: Never made it past development.